# Question and Req; Is sqlite database inside the application is possible? c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is it possible to make an application that has a sqlite database inside the application that does not show any db files? Because I don't want some people to just get there way in the application If it is possible may i request a help or some kind of example?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, that come to mind:

### In-memory

It is possible to create a sqlite database in memory, but it will obviously be deleted after you close the application. Look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/in-memory-databases

**Example:**

If you use Entity-Framework you can specify

`var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");`

Then you will not have a file on disc.

### Password-Protected

If you want to persist data after the application is closed you always will have to write something on a disc. If you want to prevent your users from manipulating it you could consider protecting it with a password.

For this you can look at:
[How to connect to sqlite database with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586502/how-to-connect-to-sqlite-database-with-password)

### Encryption

Another way would be to encrypt your database. You can look at:
[Encrypt SQLite database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp)